# Does Safari have problems with vertical text in Flexbox item, or is it me?

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

Safari 10.0 renders this example differently than Firefox, Chrome, Microsoft Edge or Microsoft Explorer: the red div fills the whole height in all of these browser and it does not in Safari. The problem seems to be with the vertical text - how to fix it?

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.inner {
  display: block;
  background: blue;
}

.test {
  display: block;
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  -moz-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  -ms-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="test">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    Two
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the exact behaviour on Safari ? the blue div sits at the bottom ?

Comment: the blue div stretches from top to bottom (as as it should) but the red div only takes a part of vertical space big enough to fit the text "One"

Comment: and does it stretch completely when you remove the vertical text behaviour ?

Comment: yes, after removing vertical text modifiers both divs "test" and "inner" stretch from top to bottom of the "outer" div

Comment: Can you try `align-items: stretch` on your container(.outer)

Comment: Adding align-items: stretch changes nothing. Actually I noticed that the original example is rendered one way on Firefox and another way on Chrome/Edge but this difference is not a problem in my case.

Comment: This accepted answer might give you an idea - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636796/chrome-safari-not-filling-100-height-of-flex-parent

Comment: My example actually follows solution 4 from the posted question: "use flexbox all the way". I cannot use absolute positioning in the real problem this little example illustrates. I would really like to fix the example somehow.